# How to add Link to my react-bootstrap Card for changing URL path

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an e-commerce website using react-bootstrap. I managed to display each of the product item using Card Component and I want the Card to be entirely clickable and when user click it the path will be change. the link is working but it turned my title, category and price color to blue and show underline. I tried to write css for the card component. but it still underline the text any way to resolve this ?

ProductList:

```
  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <h1> This is {category} page</h1>
        {productList && productList.map(product =>{
          const {id, title, price, category,image} = product;
          return(
          <Col lg={3} className="d-flex">
            <Link to={`/product/${category}/${id}`}>
              <Card key={id} className="flex-fill productlist" onClick={console.log('Clicked')}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{category}</Card.Text>
                  <Card.Text>
                    Current Price: {price}
                  </Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Link>
          </Col>
          )
        })}
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}
```

my css:

```
.card-body{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the following CSS:

```
.normal-text {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

then add a `className` to the `Link` element:

```
<Link
  to={`/product/${category}/${id}`}
  className="normal-text"
>
  <Card
    className="flex-fill productlist"
    key={id}
    onClick={console.log("Clicked")}
  >
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>{category}</Card.Text>
      <Card.Text>Current Price: {price}</Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
</Link>
```

and it will display black text without the underline in the card. Here's a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hoover-2pdv5s?file=/src/App.css

If you want to remove the styles you get for `hover`, `active` and `visited` as well, then you could change the CSS as follows:

```
.normal-text,
.normal-text:hover,
.normal-text:visited,
.normal-text:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```